# how to find Linux processes started at a certain time

Tags: top, ps, htop

I am trying to debug Linux vnc session that is not responding. I think I clicked the KDE konsole icon and that is when the vnc session became frozen. I can see the windows and menu in KDE but nothing responds. I am wondering if i could know the processes that started in the last 10 minutes to last one hour because that is when the problem started. Is there a command that can filter the processes started between start time and end time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ ls -lah /proc
```

...all of the numeric items in that directory are proccess IDs. Look at the create time for each, and you have when each process was started.

The only way you'd be able to retroactively determine process end time is if you had auditd running and configured to record process start/stop data.